# What is the current state of the crystalline analogue of the Weil conjectures?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, weil-conjectures, crystalline-cohomology

In "F-isocrystals on open varieties results and conjectures" Faltings says:

> "Finally, we extend the theory of weights and show as much as possible of the crystalline analogue of the Weil conjectures."

**My questions are:**

What is the current state of the crystalline analogue of the Weil conjectures?

Which are the articles and books about these conjectures?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As far as I can tell, [Kedlaya solved it 12 years ago.](http://arxiv.org/abs/math/0210149)